# overriding propel.xml file from FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, propel, fosuserbundle

I am extending FOSUserBundle for my project, But i dont want the email field to be a unique one, so extended the schema.xml to removed the unique tag from the xml and built the models accordingly. But when i try to register, still it checks for the uniqueness of the email via propel.xml.

username_canonical
        fos_user.username.already_used</option>-->
        
            Registration
            Profile

```
<constraint name="Propel\PropelBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueObject">
    <option name="fields">email_canonical</option>
    <!-- PropelBundle does not support custom messages yet
    <option name="message">fos_user.email.already_used</option>-->
    <option name="groups">
        <value>Registration</value>
        <value>Profile</value>
    </option>
</constraint>
```

I dont want to have that unique property to be in unique object. I couldnt override it because it takes for the specific path while loading the xml in FOSUserBundle Dependecy injection

```
$loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));

if ('custom' !== $config['db_driver']) {
    $loader->load(sprintf('%s.xml', $config['db_driver']));
}

foreach (array('validator', 'security', 'util', 'mailer') as $basename) {
    $loader->load(sprintf('%s.xml', $basename));
}
```

Can anyone please help me, how can i remove the unique constraint defined in the propel.xml

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this myself but found a solution thanks to how you posted your question.

The key is to extend the ValidationPass class in your own bundle & override the process method. I copied the validation xml files also to my own bundle under resources > config > validation and used those instead.

What I did was:

1. In my bundle (src/Example/ExampleBundle/ExampleBundle.php): define the build method and use my own ValidatorPass class
2. Copied the validation files to my own bundle & modified them
3. Copied the ValidatorPass file to my own bundle (src/Example/ExampleBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ValidatorPass.php)
4. In the ValidatorPass process method I remove the FOSUserBundle xml file and add my own

If something is not clear I can go into more detail but I think this should help you...